# Having multiple peers PeerJS?

Tags: javascript, audio, peerjs

Here is my code for connections with PeerJS:

```
var peer = new Peer({ key: '[PeerJSID]', debug: 3});
peer.on('open', function(){
  $('#my-id').text(peer.id);
});
// Receiving a call
peer.on('call', function(call){
  // Answer the call automatically (instead of prompting user) for demo purposes
  call.answer(window.localStream);
  step3(call);
});
peer.on('error', function(err){
  alert(err.message);
  // Return to step 2 if error occurs
  step2();
});
// Click handlers setup
$(function(){
  $('#make-call').click(function(){
    // Initiate a call!
    var call = peer.call($('#callto-id').val(), window.localStream);
    step3(call);
  });
  $('#end-call').click(function(){
    window.existingCall.close();
    step2();
  });
  // Retry if getUserMedia fails
  $('#step1-retry').click(function(){
    $('#step1-error').hide();
    step1();
  });
  // Get things started
  step1();
});
function step1 () {
  // Get audio stream
  navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false}, function(stream){
    // Set your video displays
    $('#my-video').prop('src', URL.createObjectURL(stream));
    window.localStream = stream;
    step2();
  }, function(){ $('#step1-error').show(); });
}
function step2 () {
  $('#step1, #step3').hide();
  $('#step2').show();
}
function step3 (call) {
  // Wait for stream on the call, then set peer video display
  call.on('stream', function(stream){
    $('#their-video').prop('src', URL.createObjectURL(stream));
  });
  // UI stuff
  window.existingCall = call;
  $('#their-id').text(call.peer);
  call.on('close', step2);
  $('#step1, #step2').hide();
  $('#step3').show();
}
```

I borrrowed this code, and I was wondering it is possible to have multiple connections between peers, like a call group. My hypothesis is that all I would have to do is add a new audio object when the peer detects that a new person is calling, and then have it so the different users receive the ids of the other users and have audio objects added to their pages as well. Would this work? Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

A peer can maintain a list of out-coming streams. For example, when a peer connects to the system, then all the other peers will get informed, and save the id of this peer to their list. When a peer tries to start a call, it then will traverse all the peers in its list. One example you can check is the [peerjs-audio-chat](https://github.com/nwah/peerjs-audio-chat) by Noah Burney.